# How to communicate between a user control and my main form?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have a few (1-3) user controls on my form. I want to be able to click a button on my form (that is not part of the user controls) and have all 3 of my user controls respond. How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "respond" ?

Comment: Well I would like for each control to do stuff with its own controls. For example by pressing a button on a main form, 3 listboxes appear on the user controls (1 on each).

Comment: i was expecting you to ask the opposite :)
how to get the form to respond for a button being clicked on the user control?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this is all you need to do; just add a public method to your user control and call that method from your button press:

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   UserControl1.DoMethod();
   UserControl2.DoMethod();
   UserControl3.DoMethod();
}

public class YourUserControl : UserControl
{ 
   public void DoMethod()
   {
      // Show your ListBoxes
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! And now I feel like an idiot! This is what happens when I stay up all night.